Automate a blank space or carriage return on NotePad ++ at certain intervals
Is it possible to automate or write a macro that will issue either a blank space(or any character) or carriage return in NotePad ++ at certain intervals?
For example, if I wanted issue the letter 'E' everytime 5mins would it be possible to automate the issuing of the letter 'E' with a macro?
I have followed the suggestion provided my Toto, however when I run the script, see image I get a black screen.

I created the generate.py file as directed, however when I search for it I'm unable to view it in the path Python Script>>Scripts>>xxxxxxx
I can now see the script generate, see image, but when I select nothing happens

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to get the 'generate' script to appear in the Menu under Scripts


You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.
If it is not yet installed, follow this guide

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
Copy this code and save the file (for example generate.py):

from time import sleep

for i in range(10):     # The text will be appended 10 times, put the value you need
    sleep(5*60)         # 5 min
    editor.appendText("\nWHATEVER YOU WANT")


Open the file you want to modify
Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> generate)
Done



Hi @Toto, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question to show the issue I am facing when I attempt to execute your script. Can you let me know what I might be doing wrong?

Hi @Toto, when I attempt to execute your code in visual studio I ge the error ""editor" is not defined"

@Patterson: To run the script, goto menu Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> generate

thanks for sticking with me on this question. Please see my update. I'm unable to view the script.

@Patterson: See my edit.

I have updated the question. Any last thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

ignore my last update. I have configured the script and it's under PytonScripts>>Scripts. Thank you. However, no text is appearing in the file I want to modify

I got it to work. I just needed to carefully follow your instructions. Thank you
